# Idiom for nepotism

Tags: idioms, expressions

When someone has connections in an organization, he can use it to good advantage to, for example, get his son a job in a company. We say:

> He pulled strings/wires to get his son the job in the company

But, what has the 'connection' done in this case?
Is there an idiom or expression defining what the owner of the organization has done? I mean something meaning "**nepotism**". But not a noun. A verb, expression or idiom.
As in:
"Mike's father pulled some strings to get him the job. The manager of the company who was his father's old friend ..... and hired him."

Comment: The person whose strings were pulled is **condoning** or **countenancing** nepotism.  Are you looking for an idiom that means "to aid and abet nepotism"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes exactly! "Aids and abet nepotism" itself sounds idiomatic though! :-D

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo but is "aiding and abetting nepotisim" what the decision maker of the company does?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if the decision-maker should be perceived as the *primary* culprit?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo
I'm looking for a job. I "pull some strings" to get the job, or maybe my father does that. (Neither my father nor I am the decision maker in the company. We just have connections there)
The manager in the company who is the decision maker in the company, hires me. What has the maneger done?

Comment: The manager has hired the son of an employee, and in so doing, has helped to establish, or perpetuate, a culture of nepotism in the organization.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo My father is not an emplyee. He knows the manager (as a relative, a friend) and has pulled strings to get me the job. The manager hired me not because I'm suited for the job but because I'm his friend's son! Is it nepotisim that the maneger has done? How do I say it in an idiomatic way? "The manager ........ and hired a friend's son"

Comment: Can we just say "the manager aided and abetted nepotism and hired his friend's son." ?

Comment: Are you asking me whether that is grammatical, whether the verbs are apt, whether it is an unbiased or biased assessment, or what?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'd like to know if "aid and abet nepotism" can be used in the context, and if it is both grammatically and semantically correct in the sentence "My father pulled some strings to get me the job, and the manager of the company who is his friend, aided and abetted nepotism and hired me." And if yes, is there also an idiom meaning the same? Thanks

Comment: It is grammatical.  It is a formula often used in criminal contexts but it need not be confined to illegalities. However, it is judgmental in its tone and amounts to a criticism of the practice of nepotism. For that reason, you would not say "...the manager of the company who is his friend aided and abetted nepotism and hired me"--not unless you were speaking facetiously, to make light of the fact that you got your job through a family connection.  The humor would suggest that you are of two minds about it.

Comment: I hereby coin _nepotize_.

Comment: You will often hear _"influence"_ or _"inside influence"_ in this context, e.g.: "He _used inside influence_ to get his son the job in the company". This describes the scenario, which involves nepotism, but only at one remove, and is less judgmental in perceived tone than "aid and abet", although it implies slight disapproval.

Comment: Dup of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316120/idiom-or-expression-related-to-nepotism

Comment: @P.E.Dant "His father used inside influence." Is his father a hiring official, or the one responsible for hiring? I'd like to know if there is a word, expression or idiom, describing the action of the person who has hired his friend's son, not the father who has used his connection to get his son the job. I know the idiom "pull strings" for the latter. The coined word nepotize sounds cool. I thought about it before, but I think I'm gonna have to wait quite a while before it gets into the vernacular! XD

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is single word for this. Probably the most common expression would be "did him a favour". Maybe one could use "smoothed the way".

If the manager did something wrong in the process it might be expressed as "broke the rules"or "bent the rules" or something more specific like "bypassed the selection process".